# For what powers $k$ is the polynomial $n^k-1$ divisible by $(n-1)^2$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials, divisibility

How do you prove this?

$$\left(n-1\right)^2\mid\left(n^k-1\right)\Longleftrightarrow\left(n-1\right)\mid k$$

Comment: Closevoters: Please use the correct reason.  This falls under "lack of context," not "not about mathematics." `:|`

Comment: Why are you trying to close it anyway ? Its not the best question but there are many many worse questions on this site.

Answer (score 5):

Let us write $m=n-1$ so we wish to show 
$$m^2|(m+1)^k-1 \Rightarrow m|k$$

Now, using the [Binomial Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem), $$(m+1)^k-1=m^k+\cdots + km$$ all terms are divisible by $m^2$ except the last and so we see $m^2|km$ implies $m|k$.

Comment: This is a special case of the double root test - see my answer.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Congruence notation helps a lot here. We want to show that $n-1$ divides $n^{k-1}+\cdots +1$ if and only if $k$ is of suitable shape.  Work modulo $n-1$, and you will get a one line proof.

Comment: Nice proof. Now I see why they have $n-1$.

Comment: It is indeed a nice illustration of the power of the idea of congruence.

Comment: ${\rm mod}\ n\!-\!1\!:\,\ \color{#c00}{n\equiv 1}\,\Rightarrow\, \color{#c00}n^{k-1}+\cdots+\color{#c00}n+1\equiv \color{#c00}1^{k-1}\!+\cdots+\color{#c00}1+1\equiv k.\,$ More generally $\,f(\color{#c00}n)\equiv f(\color{#c00}1)\,$ for a polynomial $f(x)$ with integer coefficients by the [Polynomial Congruence Rule.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** $\ $ Apply the following numerical form of the **double root test** for a polynomial $\,f(n)\,$ with integer coefficients

$$\rm\begin{eqnarray} &&\!\!\!\!\!\! (n\!-\!1)^2 |\ f(n)\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\\
\iff\ && n\!-\!1\ |\ f(n)\  &\rm and\ \ &  n\!-\!1\ \big|\ \dfrac{f(n)}{n\!-\!1}\\[.5em]
\iff\ && \color{#c00}{f(1) = 0} &\rm and&n\!-\!1\ \big|\ \left[\dfrac{f(n)-\color{#c00}{f(1)}}{n\!-\!1}\right]_{\large\, n\:=\:1}\! = f'(1) \\
\end{eqnarray}$$

So $\,f(n) = n^k-1\,\Rightarrow\,f(1)=0,\,$ and $\ f'(n) = k n^{k-1}\!\Rightarrow\,f'(1) = k,\,$ so the above criterion is $$\,(n\!-\!1)^2\mid n^k-1\iff n\!-\!1\mid f'(1) = k\qquad\qquad$$